# Django Rest Framework - JSON Model Backed Field

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-extensions

I am stuggling to get a writeable JSON field where the JSON field is backed by [JSONField](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/json.py).

**Why is `data` never correctly stored**

## models.py

```
from django_extensions.db.fields.json import JSONField

class Tracker(models.Model):

    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    identifier_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=IDENTIFIER_TYPE)

    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=DATA_TYPES)
    data = JSONField()
```

## api.py

```
class JSONSerializerField(Field):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return json.loads(data)    
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value

class TrackerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    data = JSONSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tracker
        fields = ('id', 'identifier', 'identifier_type', 'data_type', 'data')

class TrackerList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tracker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackerSerializer

class ChangeTrackerDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Tracker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackerSerializer
```

When I do a basic requests post - it NEVER pushes in the data

```
payload = {
    'data': [{'change': 1234,
               'errors': [{'count': 2, 'type': 'M1 Spacing'},
                          {'count': 1, 'type': 'M1 Over Gate Width'}],
               'results': 'fail',
               'tool': 'calibre',
               'user': 'bob',
               'version': '12.2'}],
     'data_type': 'generic',
     'identifier': 'e0f91578070ce47a048f6608e6543b6e',
     'identifier_type': 'hash'}

r = requests.post(url, payload)
r.json()
{u'data_type': u'generic', u'identifier_type': u'hash',  u'identifier': u'e0f91578070ce47a048f6608e6543b6e', u'data': {}, u'id': 4434}
```

Ref: DRF Version 3.2.5